# I am not getting proper output with nested for-loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, nested-loops

I'm supposed to get the multiplication value of the multi-dimensional array. but I am getting '1' as output whatever values being changed in array.

```js
function arrayMultiplyer(arr){
    var multi = 1;
    for(var i=0;i < arr.length; i++){
        for(var j =0; j<arr[i];j++){
            multi *= arr[i][j];
        }

    }

    return multi;
}

var multi = arrayMultiplyer([[2,33],[33,2],[5,6,9]]);
console.log(multi);
```

Comment: In the inner loop the condition should be `j < arr[i].length`

Comment: Thanks.. It's working now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check `arr[i].length` in the `j` loop.

```js
function arrayMultiplyer(arr){
    var multi = 1;
    for(var i=0;i < arr.length; i++){
        for(var j =0; j<arr[i].length;j++){ // you need to check arr[i].length here
            multi *= arr[i][j];
        }

    }

    return multi;
}

var multi = arrayMultiplyer([[2,33],[33,2],[5,6,9]]);
console.log(multi);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this in two lines.

```
function arrayMultiplyer(arr){
  let flattenedArray = arr.flat();  
  return flattenedArray.reduce((x, y) => x * y);
}

var multi = arrayMultiplyer([[2,33],[33,2],[5,6,9]]);
console.log(multi);
```

Comment: That's quite an interesting and short solution. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution using [.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```
function arrayMultiplier(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((tot,arr2) => 
    arr2.reduce((subTot, n) => 
      subTot * n
    , tot)
  , 1);
}
```